# Why is my R code geting applied to a column name?

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I am new to R so apologies if this is obvious. I am trying to manipulate daily data into monthly totals and I have managed to do so with the below code. However, I am accidentally applying some of my code to the new column name.

This is my code:

```
monthly_df <- daily_df %>%                      
  group_by(lubridate::floor_date(daily_df$daily_col_name, 'new_col_name')) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(daily_value = sum(daily_value))
```

I am trying to name this new column 'new_col_name', however the column name is this entire line of code:

'lubridate::floor_date(daily_df$daily_col_name, 'new_col_name')'

Any help as to what I am doing wrong here would be really appreciated.

Thanks all

Comment: You probably want something like `... %>% group_by(month_col = lubridate::floor_date(daily_col_name, "month")) %>% ...`. That will create a new grouping column called `month_col` which is based on the first of the month for all the dates in `daily_col_name`.

Comment: FYI, (almost) never use the original frame in the pipe as you've done here, change `floor_date(daily_df$daily_col_name` to `floor_date(daily_col_name` as JonSpring showed in that last comment. While in _this_ case it makes no difference, it's a bad habit to get into, since if there is anything else between `daily_df %>%` and your `group_by` that reorders, deletes, or changes any of the data, at best it will fail with an obtuse error, at worst it *won't* fail but your results will be incorrect/corrupted.

Comment: @r2evans also worked and noted. Appreciate the help here

Answer (score 1):

Sample data

```
daily_df <- data.frame(daily_col_name = as.Date("2022-01-01") + 0:150,
                       daily_value = 0:150)
```

We can create a new grouping column inside `group_by` using the same syntax as `mutate`. To group by month, the 2nd parameter of `lubridate::floor_date` should be "month".

```
daily_df %>% 
  group_by(month_col = lubridate::floor_date(daily_col_name, "month")) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(daily_value = sum(daily_value))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  month_col  daily_value
  <date>           <int>
1 2022-01-01         465
2 2022-02-01        1246
3 2022-03-01        2294
4 2022-04-01        3135
5 2022-05-01        4185
```